# node.js | Connect to existing game and listen in chat for events

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

So i have a weird question... I'm trying to build a bot for a game that listens to chat for certain commands and when it sees them, it responds to them.  Can I use node.js to do something like this?  Need to connect to IP with username and password to access game.

Chat & Bot Example:

```
Player 1> !doge.bot hello
Doge-Bot> Hello Player 1! How are you?
```

Hope that makes sense.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: If the service allows to do that then yes, you can do it with Node.js .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'm still learning node.js -- how would I got about making that external connection with username and pass and then "listening"?

Comment: This is not really enough information for an answer. You will need to investigate how the game itself handles login and chat. The code for a bot like this, will be completely different based on the game.

Comment: @JoshMc -- so it looks like the game uses packets to manage everything (http://twcore.com/wiki/SubspaceProtocol).  If i'm understanding this correctly, it'd probably be best to install another module like Packet (http://bigeasy.github.io/packet/) into node to help convert.  This being said... I know nothing about packets and I'd love to know more -- any recommendations?  Also, any chance you'd be willing to put together a node code snippet to help explain how it'd work?  Either way, thank you for your time!

Comment: @Birkley you are on the right track, you will need a library such as the one you linked, and you need to examine the protocol that you linked and use the packet library to communicate with the game server. I am not that familiar with this kind of raw communication, it may pay to talk to the game developers, or in the games developer forums.